# Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'dotnet' in the repo

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to deploy azure function in **.net 6** with **Linux OS** and I am getting following error :

```
[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id 'ebe37cd5e6'.
Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Running oryx build...
Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform dotnet --platform-version ~4
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20201015.1, Commit: 1a35fbce482b20b71290f3a837a3469803ce4b44, ReleaseTagName: 20201015.1

Build Operation ID: |ofFfo1rs+g4=.fd26d472_
Repository Commit : ebe37cd5e6074d0f928e688b2e718f70

Detecting platforms...
Could not detect any platform in the source directory.
Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'dotnet' in the repo.
Error: Couldn't detect a version for the platform 'dotnet' in the repo.\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform dotnet --platform-version ~4
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight
```

Does anybody know what this error means?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue on GitHub which might be related.
https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1242

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to successfully resolve it by specifying the App Service startup options (either via the Portal UI, or by using `az webapp config set --startup-file`).

You'll want "dotnet app.dll" or "dotnet app.exe" depending on how your project is configured.

There's other info out there about setting certain environment variables but none of those were successful for me, whereas setting startup worked.

Comment: You cannot specify the startup command for Azure Functions, only web apps. The asker tells us that the issue is with a Function.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are trying to deploy the function as a windows function on a Linux app.

If you are deploying through Azure DevOps, please use the parameter `appType: functionAppLinux` in the `AzureFunctionApp@1` task.

If you are using CLI deployment, please use:

`az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $RG_NAME -n $APP_NAME --src package.zip`